# SQL query get the real date and datetime difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to get the journeys that already began but not finished. I have this so far.

```
//DepartureDate and Returndate are Datetime Types

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE departureDate <= GETDATE() >= returndate";
```

Comment: soooo `WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN returndate AND departureDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE departureDate > GETDATE() AND returndate <= GETDATE()";
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, just break the logic into two parts:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.departureDate <= GETDATE() AND
      GETDATE() >= o.returndate
```